# Solr search engine Updating document

Tags: solr

I'm using solr search engine.I'm new to this. I want to update data automatically every time when my database getting update or new data created in the tables.I tried delta import and full import.In these method I have to do it manually when ever I need to update.

Which way is best for update solr document.?

How to make it automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to do this using Solr. I wouldn't recommend running a full or delta import when just updating one row in a table. What most Solr deployments do with a database is update the corresponding document when updating a row. This will be application specific, but this is the most efficient and standard way of dealing with this issue.

Using full or delta imports would be something that would run nightly or every few hours typically.

Comment: can you please give me some reference site or book for how to deploy with database?

Comment: There really isn't anything deployment specific you have to do. You just need to update Solr whenever you update your database. You can use any of the Solr clients to do this. Here is a link describing how to use the SolrJ client: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to process document before adding in solr.

This can be achieved by adding new update processor in update process chain you can go through : [Solr split joined dates to multivalue field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852254/solr-split-joined-dates-to-multivalue-field/39856027#39856027).

Here they split data in a field and saved it as multi valued field